# Jenkins github webhook integration not working?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-webhook

Using Jenkins v2.401.2

Am using [Github jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/) (comes with Jenkins) to manually configure a webhook and have it run on every action thus triggering my Jenkins job.

Getting: `POST /github-webhook/ 200 OK` when an action is triggered on Github, however the Jenkins pipeline doesn't trigger.

On Jenkins side:

- created a pipeline project
- ticked the `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling`
- ticked the `Github project` and specified the URL to my project
- created a token for my user and using it as a secret on Github (it's not needed)

Still don't see the Jenkins pipeline being triggered. Am setting the webhook via `Manual Mode`

[image]

**EDIT**

This triggers for freestyle project when selecting the appropriate checkboxes but does not work for pipeline project.

[image]

Comment: Any clues in `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > System Log`?

Comment: @VonC just checked it out, it works for the `freestyle` project but not for the `pipeline` project. The one in the question is the pipeline project.
Any idea what might be going on here.

Comment: You can [write logs from a pipeline job](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42146524/6309).

Comment: Try this similar question with answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910427/jenkins-simple-pipeline-not-triggered-by-github-push

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter why do you think I asked a new question? Tried it.

Comment: @EugenSunic fair enough. Saw it and thought it might be a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use multibranch pipeline and I don't have this problem, but if I change to pipeline I have the same behaviour.

After some tries, and check [the plugin code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/github/webhook/subscriber/DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber.java) and [this issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-35132) seems that to solve the issue you have to follow these steps (I suppose that webhooks part is well configured):

1. Use the same name on the pipeline, that the name used in the github repository. In my case this github repository: https://github.com/ConsorciAOC-PRJ/qa_payload-jenkins.git/ and the job name on jenkins `qa_payload-jenkins`.

[image]

2. As explained in the issue above, you have to register the push trigger and the job's repository, adding the following code in your pipeline, in my case:

```java
properties([pipelineTriggers([githubPush()])])

node {
    git credentialsId: 'b8d10285-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx',
        url: 'https://github.com/ConsorciAOC-PRJ/qa_payload-jenkins.git', branch: 'main'
}
```

3. You have to run once the pipeline in order that the register takes effect, then each push start triggering the job.

NOTE: I tested using `credentialsId` but you can use the autenticathion mechanism you prefer. Until git is not correct authenticated the push triggered and the job will not be registered.